# sum xml attribute in xslt not working

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<data>
    <assets>
        <details amount="100"/>
        <details amount="50"/>
        <details amount="30"/>
    </assets>
</data>
```

I would like to add amount attributes from data/assets/details by using sum function inside xslt. I did in following way which gives type conversion error

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/data/assets/details/@amount)"/>
```

Comment: Your expression appears correct, except possibly if you are using a schema-aware XPath 2.0 processor and the amount attribute has a non-numeric data type (e.g. xs:string). You need to tell us more about how you are running it, and the precise error message.

Comment: If i have a <details amount="345,78.89"/> then what should be the solution cause i guess the attribute value is the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your revised information indicates that you have amount values in the format 123,456.78. This is not a format that the automatic string-to-number conversion can handle.

So you need to do a conversion, and then you need to sum over the converted values. This is very easy in XSLT 2.0:

```
sum(/data/assets/details/@amount/number(translate(., ',', ''))
```

It's a lot more difficult in XSLT 1.0; the only clean solution is a recursive template that converts and adds each value in turn.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your solution it worked for me with my data... still so much to learn

Comment: The convention is to mark the answer as accepted. Some people care about earning brownie points (I don't), but more importantly, it's a signal to other people who find the question and answer in years to come.

Comment: I think i need at least 15 reputation to mark your respond as accepted and so far I am not allowed to do so. If you have any other way to make your respond accepted by me then i am happy to do that.

Comment: @ParaJump - You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. If you asked the question, it doesn't take any reputation to mark an answer as accepted. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour. It would also be nice of you to go back over old questions that you've asked and others have answered and see if any of them can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the below XSLT for result:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="assets">
<xsl:value-of select="details[1]/@amount + details[2]/@amount + details[3]/@amount"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```